# Не могу разобраться с SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Не могу разобраться с SharedPreferences. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она скрывалась и в SharedPreferences к примеру записывалось число 1.

При входе в приложение ещё раз считывалось бы значение с SharedPreferences, и если там значение 1, то кнопка бы не показывалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences("val", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int val = sPref.getInt("val", 0);
if( val == 0 ){
    button.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
}

.......
//в обработчике кнопки
 SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences("val", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
 editor.putInt("val",1);
 editor.commit();
```

как то так, возможны опечатки ─ нет возможности проверить, но принцип такой

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!